# How to avoid footnote number restarts from 1 each chapter?

Tags: citing

I have 3 questions:

- The footcite number restarts from 1 for each chapter, but I want it to keep increasing in sequence. How to do this?
- And in footnote, instead of [1], it looks like this: [Altiok, Tayfur; Melamed, Benjamin, Accidents or Unintentional Injuries].
- In bibliography, no [1] appears before the citation info, but I want it appearing.

How should I correct the script in order to solve these problems? (In order to make sure it works for both partcite and footnote reference, I have kept the script for them.)

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,
            style=authortitle-comp,
            natbib=true,bibstyle=numeric
            ]{biblatex}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\footnoteref[1]{\protected@xdef\@thefnmark{\ref{#1}}\@footnotemark}
\makeatother
\DeclareCiteCommand{\partcite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \mkbibbrackets{\usebibmacro{cite}}%
   \setunit{\addnbspace}
   \printnames{labelname}%
   \setunit{\labelnamepunct}
   \printfield[citetitle]{title}}%
  {\addsemicolon\space}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\partcites}{\partcite}{\addsemicolon\space}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Electronic{unintentional,
  Title                    = {Accidents or Unintentional Injuries},
  Author                   = {{Altiok, Tayfur; Melamed, Benjamin}},
  Url                      = {http://www.cdc.gov/nchs/fastats/accidental-injury.htm},
  Urldate                  = {2016-08-10}
}
@Book{HP,
  Title                    = {Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone},
  Author                   = {{Rowling,J. K. }},
  Date                     = {1997}
}

\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\chapter{this is chapter 1}
Here is a test \footnote{\label{unintentional}\partcite{unintentional}
}

\blindtext

\chapter{this is chapter 2}

This is true. \footnoteref{unintentional}.

\blindtext  \footnote{\label{HP}\partcite{HP}
}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: add option `bibstyle=numeric` to package `biblatex`. this will number your references

Comment: Your request references *chapter*s, yet `article` doesn't have `\chapter`.

Comment: thank you for the link, it´s good to know how to mark! @samcarter

Comment: sorry, I forgot to add that, I have updated the script  @Werner

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But it only shows the bibtexkey in footnote and there is no bibliography for the moment. @naphaneal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
[...]
\usepackage{remreset}
\makeatletter
\@removefromreset{footnote}{chapter}
\newcommand\footnoteref[1]{\protected@xdef\@thefnmark{\ref{#1}}\@footnotemark}
\makeatother
[...]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do

```
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout*{footnote}{chapter}
```

Here's the complete example, where I fixed the errors in the bibliography items: the authors must be separated by `and`; no double brace in that field.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[
  %backend=bibtex,
  style=authortitle-comp,
  natbib=true,bibstyle=numeric
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\footnoteref[1]{\protected@xdef\@thefnmark{\ref{#1}}\@footnotemark}
\makeatother
\DeclareCiteCommand{\partcite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \mkbibbrackets{\usebibmacro{cite}}%
   \setunit{\addnbspace}
   \printnames{labelname}%
   \setunit{\labelnamepunct}
   \printfield[citetitle]{title}}%
  {\addsemicolon\space}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\partcites}{\partcite}{\addsemicolon\space}

\counterwithout*{footnote}{chapter}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Electronic{unintentional,
  Title                    = {Accidents or Unintentional Injuries},
  Author                   = {Altiok, Tayfur and Melamed, Benjamin},
  Url                      = {http://www.cdc.gov/nchs/fastats/accidental-injury.htm},
  Urldate                  = {2016-08-10}
}
@Book{HP,
  Title                    = {Harry {Potter} and the Philosopher's Stone},
  Author                   = {Rowling, J. K.},
  Date                     = {1997}
}

\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\chapter{this is chapter 1}
Here is a test\footnote{\label{unintentional}\partcite{unintentional}}

\blindtext

\chapter{this is chapter 2}

This is true.\footnoteref{unintentional}

\blindtext\footnote{\label{HP}\partcite{HP}}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. With "and" , it only shows family name of the author, that is why I used ";" with double brace . I have checked again, the setting was not correct, I need to run Pdflatex+biblatex+pdflatex(x2)+show pdf. now in bibliography it shows correctly. But in footnote, still has the second error in my main question. So when I use "and", how to make sure it shows both family name and first name?

Comment: Plus, even with "and", in []  it still doesnt show correctly.

Comment: @Vivian It does if you use `\footcite`, so I guess that the fault is in `\partcite` (which is not the object of the question and *you* defined).

Comment: I have written in my question, I need it work for both partcite and footnote, as I need to use one citation as reference. Yes, with 
\footcite it works fine.

Comment: @Vivian The footnote number is correct; it's `\partcite` that's defined wrongly.

Comment: I have searched the manual of biblatex, but it´s really complicated and the examples inside are not so clear for me to understand. Do you have a clue how to correct it? Thank you!